# JavaScript unit test using Jenkins

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jenkins

I am actually configuring Jenkins to make a continuous integration of a JS project with unit tests. My problem is that after many researchs I didn't found any tutorial or information about how to proceed to write unit tests in Jenkins.

Should I use other tools (grunt, ant...) with Jenkins or could it do the job alone ? Is there any important plugin to install to make it work ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a testing framework with a JUnit Reporter. Jenkins can read your test results from the JUnit report and give you metrics from them.

Jenkins is just for handling the automation of building your code and running your tests in whatever language you need. In order to use it for that, you need to use something like Karma, Mocha, HapiJS's Lab, Unit.js, Jasmine, etc. to actually write and test with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where and how do I tell Jenkins to launch my tests?

Comment: Tests would be run by adding a Shell execution step or a Windows Batch execution step to a project build config. The step would call `npm test` or whatever other command you normally call for the tests, ensuring your reporter is set to JUnit output and it creates a file jenkins can find by specified path. If you have the NodeJS plugin you can also run npm scripts directly from Jenkins.